# Error in ggint$map_layout(panel, plot$facet, layer_data, plot$data) : unused argument (plot$data)

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

Luego de actualizar las librerias en `RStudio`, me salen el error que tiene que ver con la librería `ggplot2`.

```
p <- ggplot(overviewplotdata, aes(x=Dataset,
                                    y=Well, 
                                    fill=value,
                                    alpha=0.8)) 
  p <- p + geom_raster()
  p <- p + labs(x = "Knowledge Area", y = "Well") 
  p <- p + scale_colour_manual(values=c("red", "green"))
  p <- p + guides(fill=FALSE)
  p <- p + guides(alpha=FALSE)
  p <- p + theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent",
                                                colour = NA),
                  panel.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent",
                                                  colour = NA),
                  panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "grey")
                )
print(p)
```

> Error in ggint$map_layout(panel, plot$facet, layer_data, plot$data) : 
>   unused argument (plot$data)

la versión de ggplot2 es la 2.1.0

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

La versión 2.1.0 de `ggplot2` tiene problemas versiones de `plotly` 2.0.? , esto esta documentado en:

https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/481

Actualiza plotly:

https://github.com/ropensci/plotly

Comment: Gracias por responder, de plotly tengo la versión 3.4.1 pero igual no funciona.